# Swagger UI example data

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-codegen

Is there a way in swagger to show example data for; model, both input & output, query parameters, headers, etc? I have been unable to find anything related to this in the annotations documentation; 
https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/wiki/Annotations-1.5.X

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the documentation for some of the annotations mentioned in the wiki you will see they have among their optional parameters one called `example` or `examples`. You can use this parameter to add a single example or more than one (if it's allowed).

For example for a query parameter you can do it like this using the [`@ApiParam`](http://docs.swagger.io/swagger-core/current/apidocs/index.html?io/swagger/annotations/ApiParam.html) annotation:

```
@Path("/{username}")
@ApiOperation(value = "Updated user")
public Response updateUser(
  @ApiParam(example = "moondaisy") @QueryParam("username") String username
) {
...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, yeah example parameters for query params or header are pretty straight forward. I have not been able to figure out how to do body examples. A PATCH method would be especially hard because you wouldn't always want to annotate the model as it is reused for multiple endpoitns.